# logrotate suffix: dateext + rotate

Tags: linux, date, logging, logrotate

Is it possible to use dateext and rotate options at the same time?

config must look like this:

```
/var/log/verybig.log {
    monthly
    size=100M
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y%m
    rotate 5
    create
    missingok
    compress
}
```

and i must get:

```
/var/log/verybig.log
/var/log/verybig.log-201408.1.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201408.2.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201408.3.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201408.4.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201408.5.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201409.1.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201409.2.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201409.3.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201409.4.gz
/var/log/verybig.log-201409.5.gz
```

But now with this config, logrotate's debug tell me:

```
destination /var/log/verybig.201409.gz already exists, skipping rotation
```

Look like logrotate can't get multiple suffix-options, but maybe I just bad man-reader.

Using day in date format is workaround and I will not get format I want.

Answer (score 20):

You can use "date" as a suffix of the rotated file:

```
dateext dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
```

Comment: This works by adding the seconds to the date, in order to make the filename unique.  So far, it has been the only way I've been able to get multiple rotations per day working correctly.

Comment: And there is no ability to get %H%M%S (hours, minutes, and seconds) as with `date`. Only %s - seconds since 1970-01-01 (unix epoch ).

Answer (score 6):

You can use "date" as a suffix of the rotated file:

```
/tem/messages {
    rotate 5
    daily
    compress
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d.log
}
```

result： messages-2015-04-08.log.gz