# How to configure Logrotate with dateext and extension

Tags: date, ubuntu, logrotate

I tried to configure logrotate to keep the date and the extension of the log being rotated:

With the current configuration, the file:

> /var/www/redmine/log/production.log

Is logrotated in :

> /var/www/redmine/log/production.-20160710log

I was expecting :

> /var/www/redmine/log/production-20160710.log

Please see below an extract vof the logrotate configuration file :

**cat /etc/logrotate.d/redmine**

```
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    dateext

    /var/www/redmine/log/production.log
    {
            create 755 www-data www-data
            extension log
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

I Got it !

Just added the "dateformat %Y-%m-%d."
Including a "." in the format

> ```
> rotate 4
> weekly
> missingok
> notifempty
> compress
> delaycompress
> sharedscripts
> dateext
> dateformat %Y-%m-%d.
>
> /var/www/redmine/log/production.log
> {
>         create 755 www-data www-data
>         extension log
> }
> ```

Comment: I got `postgresql.2018-08-02.log` after applying the same idea. It's not quite the desired `postgresql-2018-08-02.log`, but the approach is valid.

Comment: What file name and extension you get by this setting?

Comment: I used    `dateext`     `dateformat -%Y-%m-%d.`      `addextension old`. I got `b-2022-07-21.old`

Comment: It seems `extension` is not necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507953/318765

Answer (score 3):

To get `production-20160710.log` instead of `production.2016-07-10.log` you can do:

```
dateext
dateformat -%Y%m%d

/var/www/redmine/log/production.log
{
        extension .log
}
```

The `dateformat` can actually be left out as that is the default.